# Is it possible to read all values in the form JSON JMESPath extractor that matches a regular expression in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmespath

I have following as a response from a GET call and I need to use the values like 100, 101, 102, etc in the payload of another POST call.

**Response:**

```
{"id":12,"records":[{"id":100,"documentId":1, "pageNo":1},{"id":101,"documentId":2, "pageNo":1},{"id":102,"documentId":3, "pageNo":1}]}
```

**Required Payload to be used later:**

```
{"id":12,"records":[100,101,102]}
```

Values like 100, 101, 102 will increase further with increase in data and I would require all of them.
I am using this records[*].id as regular expression. If I set match number value to 1, it returns me single value only. But I need all the values in the form of an array. How can I do so? I am using JSON JMESpath Extractor in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve it using JSON JMESPath Extractor, for some reason JMeter developers decided not to stick to the [JMESPath language specification](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) so the query like `records[*].id` returns 3 individual [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) instead of a JSON Array

Here how it should [look like](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#projections):

[image]

and here is what JMeter returns:

[image]

So I would recommend going for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and parse the response/create the next request payload in Groovy.

Example code:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

def request = [:]
request.put('id', response.id)
request.put('records', response.records.id.collect())

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(request).toPrettyString())
```

You should be able to refer the generated request data as `${request}` where required.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T
your suggestion worked for me.